# How do I navigate an association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm irritated that I'm asking this because it should be plainly obvious. But I have something wrong. I'm trying to display an attribute of a referenced model in the index.

```
Rails 4.0.0
ruby 2.0.0p247
```

app/models/unit.rb

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end
```

app/models/building.rb

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units
end
```

in console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > unit = Unit.find(3)
  Unit Load (4.1ms)  SELECT "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 => #<Unit id: 3, number: "APT 10", bed: "2", bath: "2", sqft: "300", amenities: "Stuff", building_id: 3, created_at: "2013-10-15 04:17:45", updated_at: "2013-10-15 04:37:10"> 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > unit.building.street_address
  Building Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "buildings".* FROM "buildings" WHERE "buildings"."id" = ? ORDER BY "buildings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 => "4564 Jones Ave" 
2.0.0-p247 :003 >
```

in the default index.html.erb with only one change:

```
<% @units.each do |unit| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= unit.number %></td>
          <td><%= unit.bed %></td>
          <td><%= unit.bath %></td>
          <td><%= unit.sqft %></td>
          <td><%= unit.amenities %></td>
          <td><%= unit.building.street_address %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', unit %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_unit_path(unit) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', unit, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

The only change I made was to add the ".street_address". If I add it I get an error that street_address is not a defined method. If I remove it rails will clearly show that the unit is attached to the building. What do I do?

Comment: Its good that you have posted every detail of your application. But to understand the actual error it is crucial that you post whatever Rails is throwing at you. Please post the error message as given by rails.

Comment: can u post the building model in details?

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to say that if you have orphaned `unit` records in your database (i.e. without corresponding `building` records), you can get this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error, maybe [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) will work?  Use it like this:

```
<td><%= unit.building.try(:street_address) %></td>
```